# Equivalent for DbLookupComboBox in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

What is the simplest equivalent of DbLookupComboBox using firemonkey in Delphi Seattle ?
I have googled but not found the correct solutions.

Comment: There is none. FMX relies heavily on LiveBindings.

Comment: I have tried with Live Bindings itself but could not manage it. Could you please guide.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Live binding setup]

Qart.Locate('Id',ComboArt.Tag,[]);